# Is writing a default constructor necessary?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to write a constructor for a subclass `SavingsAccount` that extends a superclass `Account`. Account already has a constructor that takes two parameters (`id` and `balance`). The constructor for `SavingsAccount` is very similar to the one for `Account`, except I need to validate `balance` differently, so I don't want to use `super(String id, int balance)` for the constructor.

When I try to create a new constructor, my IDE is telling me "There is no default constructor available in 'Account'". I don't understand why it's telling me I need a default constructor when I'm writing a new constructor in SavingsAccount.

Do I need to actually write a default constructor? Or is there something in my current constructor that isn't quite right?

Superclass:

```
public class Account extends Bank {

String id;
int balance;

Account(String id, int balance){

    if(balance < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Balance cannot be less than 0.00");

    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

And subclass:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {

String id;
int balance;

SavingsAccount(String id, int balance){
    if(balance < 1000)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Balance cannot be less than 10.00");

    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is that if you don't call super, Java will implicitly call it with no parameters. Since your superclass has no constructor with no parameters, it's not going to work...

Comment: Your `SavingsAccount` class has _two different_ `id` fields and _two different_ `balance` fields.  This is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: If you don't provide a constructor the compiler will create one for you with no arguments (and call the superclass constructor with no arguments). However it doesn't work, because your superclass already contains a nonempty constructor (so the compiler won't make one for you). So simply put, you'll need to make an appropriate constructor that calls upon the appropriate superclass constructor (as Elliott's answer shows).

Comment: Side note about your model and inheritance: `Account extends Bank` doesn't sound quite right. The usual way to determine whether you should use inheritance is the "is-a" test; an account is _not_ a bank, but a bank _has_ 1...n accounts. So, consider revising your model and using _composition instead of inheritance_ on the top level.

Comment: Another side note: by definition you cannot write a default constructor. The default constructor is the one that the compiler provides when there is no constructor in the class source code.

Comment: Thank you @MickMnemonic, Question about the side note: I got a little mixed up with that because this project was originally for Ruby and `Account` (among other things like `AccountHolders`) were supposed to go in a Module. Don't know if you're familiar with Ruby, but do you know if there is an equivalent in Java?

Comment: Good catch @LouisWasserman. I added those in while trying to find my problem and forgot to take them back out.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your constructor needs to be an invocation of the appropriate super constructor. Add `super(id, balance);` like

```
SavingsAccount(String id, int balance){
    super(id, balance);
```

which will validate that `balance` is greater than `0` and then validate the `balance` is greater than `10`. Alternatively, add an empty constructor to `Account`

```
Account() {
}
```

which will then enable your subclass to instantiate (because the compiler inserts an empty call to `super()`). Note that this is an empty constructor, the default constructor is only added if you don't define any constructors.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize the super constructor was necessary. Solution works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, this is taken [from the java docs from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

> **Note:** If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.